# How to get useChain to run animations sequentially?

Tags: react-spring

I'm trying to use react-spring to run animation X and then do animation Y. I'm using the useChain feature. It seems to run everything in parallel. What am I doing wrong? This is a super-simple scenario and I'm surprised it doesn't work AND my Googling has not turned up a lot of other people with the same problem and/or a solution. There are bugs on useChain in react-spring but they seem to cover more limited scenarios.

As an aside, I thought all React components needed to start with a capital letter so how does `animated.div` pass the compiler?

[code sandbox simple example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tryingsequentialanimation-74tpn?file=/src/Shaker.tsx)

This is my component. The box moves diagonally, not in the X axis and then in the Y axis.

```
export const Shaker = () => {
  const xRef = useSpringRef();
  const { x } = useSpring({
    from: { x: 0 },
    to: { x: 1 },
    config: config.molasses,
    ref: xRef
  });
  const yRef = useSpringRef();
  const { y } = useSpring({
    from: { y: 0 },
    to: { y: 1 },
    config: config.molasses,
    ref: yRef
  });
  useChain([xRef, yRef]);
  return (
    <animated.div
      style={{
        width: "10rem",
        height: "10rem",
        backgroundColor: "green",
        marginLeft: x.to((i) => i * 600 - 300),
        marginTop: y.to((i) => i * 600 - 300)
      }}
    ></animated.div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

They say this is a bug in react-spring but don't provide the number of the duplicate.

https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/1605